# How to get YouTube video embedded inside a specified container?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Application in : Ionic - Cordova - Angular

HTML block is as follows :

```
<div style='width:100%;height:320px'>
    <iframe src="***" style='width:100%;'></iframe>
</div>
```

Above code loads an YouTube Video inside div block.

Requirements :

a) In portrait - video size should be 100% * 320px ------ > Working fine.

b) In landscape - Video size should be 100% * 100% -------->  **Inconsistent Behaviour**

Analysis :

Case (b) is not working in all situations.

Screen is in landscape mode but video is not visible, it is playing in background. We can hear audio.

Inspected in chrome - saw YouTube video embedded has height and width set to 100% in landscape mode but still video is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used height as 320px  so when in  landscape mode the hight is also taking up 320px which is causing the inconsistency.

try making the height as 100%

```
<div style='width:100%;height:100%'>
    <iframe src="***" style='width:100%;'></iframe>
</div>
```

or as per height space.

Comment: Tried now .. still issue persists

Comment: provide the height property for the iframe as well... like <iframe src="***" style='width:100%; height:100%; '></iframe>

Comment: But requirement is -- In portrait 100% * 320px and in landscape 100% * 100% .. I tried with media queries for the same .. Portrait works fine but landscape shows black screen but audio plays

Comment: One more observation -- this happens only on first landscape tilt .. from second onwards this works fine

Comment: Problem is with allowfullscreen attribute .. If I remove this it works perfectly fine but I need this since fullscreen comes with page header ..